# How to add my custom buttons with ids to a dialog-modal jquery object

Tags: jquery, button, dialog

I would like to add custom buttons (with ids, so they can be clicked and have an action happen), added to my dialog modal object.

I would like there to be some text, and then have the buttons below the text in the modal dialog box.

Right now I have:

Javascript:

```
$("#dialog-modal").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    height: 250,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    dialogCLass: 'main-dialog-class'
});

$("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");

var text = '';
text = "This is a test";

$('#dialog-modal').text(text);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="{{$artist->stage_name}} in {{Auth::user()->city}}!"></div>
```

I would like to add a button that looks like:

```
<a class="facebook-button" id="facebook" style="color: white; font:14px / 14px 'DINMedium','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.html()` to add html contents like button or a tags etc to div

you can use to you a tag like this :-

```
$('#dialog-modal').html('<a class="facebook-button" id="facebook" style="color: white; font:14px / 14px 'DINMedium','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Share on Facebook</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [buttons](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) option to add custom buttons on your dialog:

add the option like this:

```
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({ 
        buttons: [{ text: "Share on Facebook",
                click: function() {
                    // your function here
                }
        }]
    });
```